# GeoJSON Overlay not showing up on D3 GoogleMap

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, overlay, geojson

I'm trying to follow this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Vjxpr/)  and use Ireland's shapefiles to highlight it's provinces.

```
<html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/2.10.0/d3.v2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<style>

    #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .SvgOverlay {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;           
    }
```

I'm getting the shapefiles from here: http://www.cso.ie/en/census/census2011boundaryfiles/ and converting  **Census2011_Province_generalised20m.zip** to GeoJson format using http://www.mapshaper.org/.

When I overlay this on top of GoogleMaps using D3, nothing is displayed. Could someone please help me. TIA.

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f405v66h/)

Comment: Your GeoJson coordinates are not valid latitudes/longitudes for Google Maps (latitude must be between +/-90)

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how I can export it to GeoJson using Mapshaper into that format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose the following solution:

- Convert shapefile into GeoJSON using [ogr2ogr web client](http://ogre.adc4gis.com/). Since
  the specified shapefile uses EPSG:29902 coordinate system, set
  `Target SRS:EPSG:4326` to convert it to [World Geodetic System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System)
- Once GeoJSON file is ready
  ([Census2011_Province_generalised20m.json](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/440708612b574764c309)), you could utilize
  [Google Maps Data Layer API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer) to render it as demonstrated below:

**Example**

```js
function initMap()
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {
                lat: 53.349248,
                lng: -6.255323
            },
            zoom: 6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });
    var dataLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    dataLayer.loadGeoJson('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vgrem/440708612b574764c309/raw/2a4e2feadc204806440c51a14c2ef1f54f4fc3d8/Census2011_Province_generalised20m.json');
    dataLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
#map {
   width: 800px;
   height: 640px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

**Result**

[image]